# Is there any way to visually change representation for particular editor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I often simultaneously open similar files placed in different locations, like `Dockerfile` - one in my project and one in example folder. This confuses me because I often try to edit wrong file. I made an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deitry.workspace-watchdog) which colorize files outside current workspace, but I was able to change color only for text background, not editor's one. That does solve the problem, but still looks imperfect and interfere with VS Code's own text background changes, like when selecting text.

Is there any way to change editor color only for specific files without doing some magic through [Custom CSS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)? **Or is there any other way to visually separate these files?**

---

My first attempt on that problem was to play with  `"editor.rulers"` option - if set in User settings for `[10,20,30,40,50]` and for `[100]` in workspace folder that visually change representation for non-workspace files, but actually looks awkward.

I am aware of `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"editor.background": ...}` option, but this one change background for *all* editors; I didn't find a way to make it different for two editors opened in same VS Code instance.

Also there is always a solution to open more than one instance of VS Code for each workspace folder, each with its own theme, but this results in bad performance on slow machines; and I didn't found how to open more than one instance for *same* workspace folder.

Upd. This is how looks with my Workspace Watchdog extension.
[image: Visually separate files with Workspace Watchdog extension]

Comment: I know it is visually not compelling, but if you open two or more files with the same name you see the path next to their names in the tabs like here: https://pasteboard.co/IHo2711.png

Comment: @JohnArcher this is not correct if you open both in separate columns. See attached image in question update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can distinguish the files using breadcrumbs. Insert the following into your settings.json file (Ctrl+, or CMD+,):

```
"breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
"breadcrumbs.filePath": "on",
"breadcrumbs.symbolPath": "off",
"breadcrumbs.symbolSortOrder": "position"
```

Check out the screenshot below.
[image]

[I've created a video on it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mM-SZsLCK8&t=1s)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice catch, thank you! I found my `"breadcrumbs.filePath"` set to `"last"` so it showed only filename. I remember that when breadcrumbs feature was introduced, it always showed full path, which was very confusing - while in recent versions of VS Code it shows only difference from `${workspaceFolder}` path. I'll wait a bit for another suggestions, but if there will be none, I'll mark this as a solution.

Comment: You're most welcome. I've also edited my answer to include a video I created on the breadcrumbs.filePath setting.